# How would I create a log-normal toy data set of compositional data (the observations are proportions of a constant sum)?

Tags: r, distribution

I am writing a module for a geostatistics class and I want to generate a log-normally distributed data set of compositional data (where each row in the data set sums to a constant sum, i.e. 1 or 100 or any constant sum).

Here's a toy data set:

```
n <- 9

prefix <- "Sample"

suffix <- seq(1:n)

sampleNames <- paste(prefix, suffix, sep = "")

set.seed(129)
toy <- data.frame(sample = sampleNames,
                  A = c(rlnorm(9, 1.5, 1)),
                  B = c(rlnorm(9, 0.2, 1)),
                  class = c(rep("Class1", 3), rep("Class2", 3), rep("Class3", 3)))

toy$Sum <- rowSums(toy[2:3])

toy

   sample         A         B  class       Sum
1 Sample1  1.460969 0.4537178 Class1  1.914687
2 Sample2  1.665750 3.7877504 Class1  5.453500
3 Sample3  1.133492 0.9560655 Class1  2.089557
4 Sample4  1.155294 4.0013225 Class2  5.156617
5 Sample5 33.008178 0.2295724 Class2 33.237750
6 Sample6  8.987817 1.1252450 Class2 10.113062
7 Sample7  9.698469 0.1956622 Class3  9.894131
8 Sample8  4.468949 1.7486894 Class3  6.217639
9 Sample9 12.287083 2.9791524 Class3 15.266236
```

So creating a dataset of log-normal data is easily done, but I am not clear how I would ensure that the rows of numeric data sum to the same constant (any constant would do, but it must be the same for each row).

Comment: Scaling preserves a distribution's shape, so is there any reason you couldn't just divide A and B by Sum (or by 100*Sum)?

Comment: @pjs That did it, thank you for the assistance!